# Celery keeps trying to connect to localhost instead of Amazon SQS

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, celery, amazon-sqs

So I'm trying to setup Celery in my Django project, and using Amazon SQS as my broker. However, Celery keeps trying to find SQS on localhost for some reason.

This is my `settings.py`:

```
CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT = "sqs"
CELERY_BROKER_USER = env.str("DJANGO_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
CELERY_BROKER_PASSWORD = env.str("DJANGO_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {
    "region": env.str("DJANGO_AWS_SQS_REGION_NAME", default="us-east-2"), 
    "polling_interval": 10,
}
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = "default"
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ["application/json"]
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = "json"
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = "json"
CELERY_CONTENT_ENCODING = "utf-8"
CELERY_ENABLE_REMOTE_CONTROL = False 
CELERY_SEND_EVENTS = False
CELERY_SQS_QUEUE_NAME = "default"
```

This is my `celery.py` :

```
import os

from celery import Celery

# set the default django settings module
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings.production')

app = Celery('consumers')  # type: Celery

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

When I start the worker using `celery -A src.consumers worker --loglevel=debug`, the worker tries to start with the following output and then immediately stops:

```
 -------------- celery@aditya-PC v5.2.7 (dawn-chorus)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-5.15.0-52-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35 2022-10-27 13:56:01
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         consumers:0x7fd77051de40
- ** ---------- .> transport:   sqs://AHJJHHFYTA3GHVJHB8:**@localhost:6379//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 12 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
                

[tasks]
  . celery.accumulate
  . celery.backend_cleanup
  . celery.chain
  . celery.chord
  . celery.chord_unlock
  . celery.chunks
  . celery.group
  . celery.map
  . celery.starmap
  . src.consumers.tasks.app1_test
```

How can I make celery not try to connect to localhost, and connect to SQS instead?

Answer (score 0):

Hey this is kind of a non issue. The way it is mounted makes it look like localhost but it actually writes to the queue.

```
[2022-10-27 18:46:53,847: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to sqs://localhost//
```

This is a log from our prod env and everything works
create a message in sqs and you will see it gets processed